# converting swift code to delphi - procedure of object

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have a trouble to translate in delphi the function below

```
- (BOOL)registerForTaskWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
                           usingQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue 
                        launchHandler:(void (^)(__kindof BGTask *task))launchHandler;
```

and this is an example of usage :

```
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: 'toto', using: nil) { (task) in

       task.expirationHandler = {
         task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
       }

     }
```

This is the delphi conversation I made of the header :

```
  BGTaskScheduler = interface(NSObject)
    function registerForTaskWithIdentifier(identifier: NSString; usingQueue: dispatch_queue_t; launchHandler: TBackgroundTasksLaunchHandler) : Boolean; cdecl;
  end;

  BGTask = interface(NSObject)
    procedure setExpirationHandler(expirationHandler: TBackgroundTasksExpirationHandler); cdecl;
  end;
```

But I don't understand How I can do this part in delphi :

```
       task.expirationHandler = {
         task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
       }
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Swift but based on code I would guess that last code that you have shown might be assigning a specific method to some event handler so that such method will be executed once that even fires. I might be wrong.

Comment: @SilverWarior yes I think exactly the same as you, the only problem is that as far as i know their is no concept of procedure of object in Objective c interface to delphi. I m wrong ?

Comment: In Delphi the interface itself can not store any data on its own. So it is not possible for you to store reference to object method as the example code does. But reading [BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) the task scheduler is actually declared as class and not interface. Now as far as I know in order for interface to access class fields it needs to use class own methods to do that. But my knowledge on working with interfaces in Delphi is pretty basic so I might be wrong

Comment: finally I found, their is method like SetexpirationHandler that can do the trick :)